# If Pi were equal to 3, time travel possible?

Tags: circles, pi

In Algebra 2 back in high school, there was a math teacher that taught at Princeton who mentioned that if pi were 3, we could be talking about time travel and also travel through dimensions.

Why would pi being 3 and instead of 3.14159.....etc etc allow us to be able to think about traveling through time and dimensions?

Comment: "Ex falso quodlibet." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion Or he was just joking. In any case, this seems to not be a question about math.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg gotcha, where could i ask this question then?

Comment: @and1: It would appear that the only person capable of answering your question is your Algebra 2 instructor.

Comment: This type of question doesn't fit well with the Stack Exchange format, so I would suggest Quora. Have a look at this [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/In-the-multiverse-other-universes-will-have-different-values-of-physical-constants-such-as-c-and-G-Could-they-also-have-different-values-of-mathematical-constants-such-as-Pi-and-e) and see if that answers your question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg He or she or they were joking.

Comment: @Blue why would she be the only one? im sure other geniuses like her would be able to explain at least why that would even come up

Comment: I don't think that her statement is based on any law of mathematics or physics. On second thoughts, you really should ask her as no one else can know exactly what she was thinking.

Comment: @and1, not only did she joke, she was sarcastic. In fact, it is a common thing in my homeland. For example: 'If what you said were true, I'm Donald Trump.

Comment: The teacher could have been a flakey kook and been serious.  But more likely she was just trying to explain a false hypothesis implies anything.  The only way that $\pi = 3\implies $ time travel can be false, is if we can ever have a case where $\pi = 3$ but we don't have time travel.  But since $\pi \ne 3$ that can never happen.  So $\pi = 3 \implies $ time travel can never be false.  So it is true.  But because $\pi$ will never be $3$ it doesn't do us any good.

Comment: @TobyMak gotcha, this was over 15 years ago so can't ask her anymore, i vaguely remember her mentioning something to do with math/theoretical physics but not sure exactly

Comment: @fleablood i think it's one of those things that the average joe won't understand unless they get into theoretical physics and higher order math. I won't disagree that she was somewhat eclectic but she was not dumb or someone that would conjure stuff up out of the blue for fun or anything

Comment: "hink it's one of those things that the average joe won't understand unless they get into theoretical physics and higher order math. "  Then she was probably a nut.  They exist.  They even teach.  But $\pi \ne 3$ so this can't work.  I imagine its something about gravity having different strengths.  It's not valid.

Comment: @fleablood i guess?? this might be a question i'll have to ask someone that's in theoretical physics or something. She was talking about math stuff that went way over my head.

Comment: @and1: Your instructor is the only person who *really* knows whether she was joking, or can say whether she was trying to make a point that may have been mis-construed, or whatever. ... I'll note that there *is* a well-known [paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) about how traveling in a circle at relativistic speeds causes the traveler to perceive the "circumference-over-diameter" ratio as something other than 3.1415..., allowing one to cheekily (but improperly) claim that they've "changed the value of pi". That's not really a time/dimension-travel thing, though.

Comment: @Blue gotcha, yeah she was being dead serious and i should say that she mentioned if pi was 3, we `could` be talking about that kind of stuff, not that people could actually do it but i understand what you're saying

Comment: @GregMartin: Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Blue probably has it.  She was probably talking about that paradox.  Or maybe its some figure fiddling.  Given certain conditions and values of gravitational fields time travel would be possible (my understanding is they are impossible reconstruct  and would require nearly all the existant energy in the universe).  If $\pi = 0.95 \pi$ you can probably do a bunch of calculations that will hammer conditions within that margin of error.

Answer (score 4):

A false hypothesis implies anything.

If you have fourteen fingers, then there is an invisible purple dragon in my garage.

Pf:  The only way this can be false if somehow you have fourteen fingers and I *don't* have an invisible purple dragon in my garage.

But that can't happen because you simply do not have fourteen fingers.

So this can't be false.  So it is true.   Every time you have fourteen fingers (all zero of the times) were also the zero times I has an invisible purple dragon in my garage.

And likewise every time $\pi =3$ happens, time travel exists.

Comment: Perfect answer !

Comment: Is it though???